# How to render Viva Pinata fur

Tags: rendering, gpu

[image]

[image][image]

[image]
In the game Viva Pinata, cute virtual animals have color changing paper cut like furs.

It didn't seem like using shell rendering because there are LOTS of animals in a scene and shell rendering each every one of them to render these furs sounded like a daunting process for a game.

I tried to build 3d model with each triangle but that didn't seem like right solution either.

I am out of my tricks in my pocket.

Comment: I don't think this uses any kind of  shader to create those paper pieces, it's just a couple hundred quads

Comment: no http://www.maxon.net/en/customer-stories/games-interactive/singleview/article/viva-la-viva-pinata.html

Comment: are there chances the rendering is obtained somehow with the 3d editing program?

Comment: @BlueBug - that link basically tells you what it is, and if you look at BodyPaint3D's website you can get even more info on how the UV mapping works.  The shader most likely overdraws the color off from the body for a starting point of being on the body.  Many many scraps of "paper" are used to make things look rounded, but it's really just rectangles of color popping straight off the body at regular intervals.